# How to use a managed instance with parameter at two different places in Wire?

Tags: hiconic

I have a `@Managed` instance that requires a parameter to further qualitfy its display information:

```
@Override
@Managed
public Folder reportsFolder(String displayName) {
    Folder bean = create(Folder.T).initFolder("reports", displayName);
    // further settings
    return bean;
}
```

As you can see on the `@Override` annotation, I expose this bean via a contract.
In different contextual environments, I utilize the bean in two distinct contexts, resulting in varying display names. One instance is highly specific, while the other is context-sensitive.
I add my folder to another folder's subfolders via

```
myContract.reportsFolder("Reports") // respectively displayName = Accounting Reports
```

When starting my server, I get following exception in the workbench access:

> Root cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Another entity is already indexed (com.braintribe.model.generic.GenericEntity:globalId) for key 'wire://MyWireModule/MyWbSpace/reportsFolder'. ADDED ENTITY: Folder[@1819253230,content=FolderContent[@1663561273,id=null],deniedFor=set[size=0],displayName=LocalizedString[@673255435,id=null],effectiveDeniedFor=set[size=0],effectiveGrantedFor=set[size=0],globalId="wire://MyWireModule/MyWbSpace/reportsFolder",grantedFor=set[size=0],icon=Icon[@1627227607,id=null],id=null,name="reports",parent=null,partition=null,securityPolicy=null,subFolders=list[size=0],tags=set[size=0]], INDEXED ENTITY: Folder[@672502595,content=FolderContent[@655321454,id=null],deniedFor=set[size=0],displayName=LocalizedString[@632749657,id=null],effectiveDeniedFor=set[size=0],effectiveGrantedFor=set[size=0],globalId="wire://MyWireModule/MyWbSpace/reportsFolder",grantedFor=set[size=0],icon=Icon[@1127591009,id=null],id=null,name="reports",parent=null,partition=null,securityPolicy=null,subFolders=list[size=0],tags=set[size=0]]
>
> Wrapper #1: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while constructing bean Folder[@1819253230,content=FolderContent[@1663561273,id=null],deniedFor=set[size=0],displayName=LocalizedString[@673255435,id=null],effectiveDeniedFor=set[size=0],effectiveGrantedFor=set[size=0],globalId="wire://MyWireModule/MyWbSpace/reportsFolder",grantedFor=set[size=0],icon=Icon[@1627227607,id=null],id=null,name="reports",parent=null,partition=null,securityPolicy=null,subFolders=list[size=0],tags=set[size=0]]

I was expecting that I don't have to further qualify my managed instance.